# ¿Cómo puedo poner una Galeria de Imagen dentro de un "Artículo" utilizando Joomla?

Tags: php, imagen, xampp, joomla3

Lo intenté usando el plugin: **Simple Gallery Images**

Pero al hacer todo el procedimiento, me tira el siguente error:

> Simple Image Gallery Notice: It looks like PHP's 'GD Image Library' is not installed/enabled on your system. Please ask your hosting company to enable/install it.

Aclaro que mi pagina todavia esta en diseño y estoy usando el Servidor Local `Xampp`

Answer (score 0):

1. Busca en esta ruta **C:\xampp\php\ext** y verifica si existe la extensión **gd2**. Si no existe, la puedes descargar.
2. Busca y abre tu archivo de configuración **C:\xampp\php\php.ini** y en el, busca esta línea **extension=gd2**. Borra el **;** (punto y coma) que tiene delante para descomentar la línea y así habilitas la extensión.
3. Reinicia tu servidor `XAMPP`
4. Prueba de nuevo y nos comentas como te fue.